# Open a square box to show content when clicked on hyperlink using html/java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried many ways to create a square box which will show content when clicked on hyperlink. Please help me with the code in html/JavaScript.

Comment: Can you include what you've tried in the question so that we can see where you may be going wrong?

Comment: Please be a bit more descriptive about your question by explaining where do you want the box, does the box get data from database or it has custom content or similar things if you need a specific answer.

Comment: Custom content in the box , no need to get any info from data base.

Comment: I just want the box to show up when clicked on hyperlink, that box will show static content.

Answer (score 0):

First, add link to your page:

```
<a id='showContent'></a>
<div id='content' style='display: none;'></div>
```

Than use some jQuery to show content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showContent').click(function(event){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent link from following it's href
        $('#content').toggle();
    });
});
```

Toggle will switch display state from `display: none` to `display: block` and from `display: block` to `display.none`.
You can use `show` and `hide` instead.
To show with animation: `slideDown` / `fadeIn`;
hide: `slideUp` / `fadeOut`;
toggle: `slideToggle` / `fadeToggle`

Comment: Thank you, but in between which tags should I paste them?

Comment: @user3921855 js goes to `<script>` tag and rest of html goes to `<body>` tag... And don't forget to load jQuery library (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)